# What are the data formats that Cloud ML batch prediction supports today?

Tags: google-cloud-ml

I have the inference graph constructed in my trained model and would like to use batch prediction to predict many records. How can I specify the inputs in the input file(s)?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please see **[How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)** and **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**. [Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39782288/edit) the post to add relevant code in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Cloud ML supports three data formats so far. One is text file, each line of which is a record you want to predict over. The second and third formats are [TFRecords](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/python_io.html#tfrecords-format-details); both compressed and gzip-compressed are supported. A TFRecord file is a container to store bytes,typically binary data, e.g. serialized Example proto. These bytes get fed directly into the prediction graph. You must specify them in the data_format field (TEXT, TF_RECORD, TF_RECORD_GZIP)  in the request.

For text format, each line is either a JSON object or a UTF8 string. In case of the former, the keys are input tensor names and the values are the data that will be fed into the inference graph. If your graph has only one input tensor, you can skip the JSON and just save newline delimited strings.

Here are some examples:

## You have four input tensors, namely index, height, name, and image

```
{“index”: 100, “height”: 5.5, “name”: “Alice”, “image”: [0.0, 0.0, 0.123, 0.17,0,0]}
{“index”: 101, “height”: 5.8, “name”: “John”, “image”: [0.0, 0.21, 0.09, 0.5, 0,0]}
...
```

## You have one string input tensor. No need to specify the name.

```
“This is a string input”
“That is another string input”
...
```

## You have one tensor with scalar type. No need to specify the name.

```
1445
425
3412
...
```

## You have one input tensor, which is a numpy array. No need to specify the name.

```
[0, 3.14, 2.718, 0.0, 1.414]
[1.618, 299.7, 8.314, 0.0, 0.0]
...
```

Note that the names in the mutliple-tensor inputs case must match the [aliases](https://cloud.google.com/ml/docs/how-tos/preparing-models) defined in the inputs collections in the inference graph.